# Comparar dos archivos CSV, imprimir una salida con valores agregados usando Java

Tags: java, csv

Tengo los siguientes archivos .csv leídos en Java.

El primer archivo csv contiene la siguiente información **(semestres)**:

```
3,Primavera
5,Primavera
5,Verano
12,Primavera
10,Verano
22,Otono
```

El segundo archivo csv contiene **(carreras)**:

```
3,bachiller en ciencias    
5,bachiller en artes    
12,artes culinarias    
15,maestria en artes    
22,maestria en ciencias
```

Sin embargo, la salida en terminal *(no en otro CSV)* debería ser así:

**(salida)**

```
3,bachiller en ciencias,Primavera
5,bachiller en artes,Primavera,Verano
12,artes culinarias,Primavera
15,maestria en artes
22,maestria en ciencias,Otono
```

¿Comó puedo hacer para que la salida se cumpla, es decir, para que se comparen los códigos de las carreras con los códigos de carreras en semestres, y así, agregar al final en que otros semestres son ofrecidas, tal como muestra el ejemplo?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Comment: Con esta librería podrías hacerlo: https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/#to-read-all-rows-of-a-csv-the-quick-and-easy-way Te permite crear  fácilmente un mapa del primer CSV y luego unirlo con el segundo CSV o viceversa. A través de opciones de la librería puedes decidir qué columnas quieres unir durante la lectura (las columnas empiezan por 0).

Comment: @A.Cedano, ¿considerarías colocar tu comentario como una respuesta?

Comment: No considero que esta pregunta _sea demasiado amplia_ Es más, es un caso que se podría repetir en el futuro.

Answer (score 2):

Hay una librería que te permite leer fácilmente archivos CSV. Se trata de [Univocity Parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/#to-read-all-rows-of-a-csv-the-quick-and-easy-way)

Por ejemplo, para leer un CSV:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    //the file used in the example uses '\n' as the line separator sequence.
    //the line separator sequence is defined here to ensure systems such as MacOS and Windows
    //are able to process this file correctly (MacOS uses '\r'; and Windows uses '\r\n').
    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");

    // creates a CSV parser
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    // parses all rows in one go.
    List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(getReader("/examples/example.csv"));
```

Para hacer lo que planteas en la pregunta, bastaría con leer un archivo, archivarlo en un Map, y luego leer el segundo, archivarlo en otro Map o en una lista y luego combinarlos.

---

Te dejo un ejemplo que podría servirte, aunque quizá tengas que darle algunos retoques:

#### Primero leemos uno de los archivos CSV y generamos un Map:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    //First we parse one file (ideally the smaller one)
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    //here we tell the parser to read the CSV headers
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    //Parse all data into a list.
    List<String[]> records = parser.parseAll(new File("/path/to/csv1.csv"));
    //Convert that list into a map. The first column of this input will produce the keys.
    Map<String, String[]> mapOfRecords = toMap(records);

    //this where the magic happens.
    processFile(new File("/path/to/csv2.csv"), new File("/path/to/diff.csv"), mapOfRecords);

}
```

#### Este es el código para generar un Map desde la lista de registros:

```
    /* Converts a list of records to a map. Uses element at index 0 as the key */
private static Map<String, String[]> toMap(List<String[]> records) {
    HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    for (String[] row : records) {
        //column 0 will always have an ID.
        map.put(row[0], row);
    }
    return map;
}
```

#### Con el mapa de registros, podemos procesar el segundo archivo CSV y generar otro Map con los datos actualizados:

**Nota:** En la pregunta en inglés se trataba de comparar dos archivos, quizá para tu caso en esta etapa haya que agregar el dato que falta del segundo archivo. El ejemplo es adaptable.

```
private static void processFile(final File input, final File output, final Map<String, String[]> mapOfExistingRecords) {
    //configures a new parser again
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    //All parsed rows will be submitted to the following Processor. This way you won't have to store all rows in memory.
    settings.setProcessor(new RowProcessor() {
        //will write the changed rows to another file
        CsvWriter writer;

        @Override
        public void processStarted(ParsingContext context) {
            CsvWriterSettings settings = new CsvWriterSettings(); //configure at till
            writer = new CsvWriter(output, settings);
        }

        @Override
        public void rowProcessed(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
            // Incoming rows from will have the ID as index 0.
            // If the map contains the ID, we'll get a row
            String[] existingRow = mapOfExistingRecords.get(row[0]);

            if (!Arrays.equals(row, existingRow)) {
                writer.writeRow(row);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void processEnded(ParsingContext context) {
            writer.close();
        }
    });

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    //the parse() method will submit all rows to the RowProcessor defined above. All differences will be
    //written to the output file.
    parser.parse(input);
}
```

Fuente: [Stackoverlow en inglés: Java compare two csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40990287/5587982)

Comment: Sugieres, entonces, la creacion de un archivo adicional, los dos originales mas uno nuevo. La idea es imprimir en consola la muestra.

Comment: @Mr.Munoz Es un código de ejemplo. Si no necesitas el archivo adicional no tienes que crearlo, solamente imprimes con `System.out.println` el contenido del mapa en el que has unido los valores. Imprimir o guardar es algo adicional que puedes hacer o no de acuerdo a tus requerimientos.